# how click on link then scrolling and show div

Tags: html, css

I have 3 title, like this:

```
<a href="#">title 1</a>
<a href="#">title 2</a>
<a href="#">title 3</a>
```

And i have 3 div that explained them, like this:

```
<div id="one">there is a describe for title 1</div>
<div id="two">there is a describe for title 2</div>
<div id="three">there is a describe for title 3</div>
```

Point: Each describe is multi-line (this page have overflow-y:scrool and height of this page is too lengthy)

Now i want when user click on title 1, page scrolls and show `<div id="one">`, and so on for other title.

Point: via HTML or CSS or both of them, NOT JS

Comment: Have you tried `<a href="#one">title 1</a>`?

Comment: @rsilva i did it and worked correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:

```
<a href="#one">title 1</a>
```

and worked correctly ...!